# Can warmer winters yield more infestations of fleas (and of other insects)?

Tags: fleas

Can warmer winters yield more infestations of fleas (and other insects)?

In 2023, while the North Hemisphere has been experimenting heat domes, South America has been experimenting a particularly warm winter. I am experimenting (what I believe to be) a flea infestation (when I am not even currently living nor working with dogs, just with two quaker parrots and three chickens), and when I commented about it, several other persons from the regions mentioned that they had experimented flea bites recently.

I am wondering if there is a correlation with milder winters and an increase in the risk and frequency of fleas infestation?

Comment: this question is a better fit over at https://biology.stackexchange.com/ but you will need to show that you have tried to find an answer on your own first.

Comment: It would certainly be expected to change the habitat zones of animals, including insects and arachnids. There's already some evidence that suggests this is occurring. No idea about fleas, specifically.